# All new Laravel instances are broken (with Laravel installer)

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-valet

Something seems to be wrong with freshly created Laravel instances on my machine.

- laravel new demo -> "Application ready! Build something amazing."
- Open http://demo.test/
- Exception gets thrown:

  ```
  Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible 
  with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)
  ```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Additional information:

- laravel/installer version: 2.3.0
- laravel/valet version: 2.5.3
- composer version: 1.7.2
- PHP version: 7.2.24

Comment: The same problem with ```composer create-project laravel/laravel demo```

Comment: There is a bug report filed at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34506 - have you checked whether this matches your situation?

Answer (score 1):

#### Try to do this steps:

- Change to `"symfony/translation": "4.3.8"` in your `composer.json`
- Run `composer update` once again

#### If not solved:

- Make sure to run `valet install` once again from the `root` terminal.